# How to derive this equation about the independence event and conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I read the content from page 6 to 7 in chapter one of the book "Quantum information Meets Quantum Matter",

> Now suppose that the joint distribution $p_{AB}(\omega_i,\lambda_m)$ has no correlation at all, and then from Alice’s point of view, her outcome is independent of Bob’s out- come. In other words, whatever Bob’s outcome is, the probability distribution of Alice’s outcome should be just the same. This means that the conditional probability $p_{A \mid B}(\omega_i,\lambda_m)$ should not depend on $\lambda_m$, i.e.,
> $$
> p_{A \mid B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=p_{A \mid B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_n\right), \forall i, m, n \quad (1.10)
> $$
> Similarly, from Bob’s point of view, one should have
> $$
> p_{B \mid A}\left(\lambda_m, \omega_i\right)=p_{B \mid A}\left(\lambda_m, \omega_j\right), \forall i, j, m \quad (1.11)
> $$
> We will show that the condition of (1.10) and (1.11) implies that the joint prob- ability distribution equals the product of the probability distributions of each party, i.e.,
> $$
> p_{A B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=p_A\left(\omega_i\right) p_B\left(\lambda_m\right), \forall i, m \quad (1.12)
> $$
> and vice versa. In other words, the conditions (1.11) and (1.12) are just equivalent. To see this, we first show how to go from (1.11) to (1.12). For $\forall m, i$ we have for $\forall j$,
> $$
> p_{B \mid A}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=p_{B \mid A}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)=\frac{p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}{p_A\left(\omega_j\right)} \quad (1.13)
> $$
> Then
> $$
> p_{B \mid A}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{d_A-1} p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}{\sum_{j=0}^{d_A-1} p_A\left(\omega_j\right)}=p_B\left(\lambda_m\right) \quad (1.14)
> $$

Here A and B are two independent objects and the possible outcomes for A is the set $\{ \omega_i, i = 0, d_A - 1 \}$, the possible outcomes for B is the set $\{ \lambda_i, i = 0, d_A - 1 \}$. The object A is for Alice and object B is for Bob.

I can derive the last equation 1.14 using the Bayes’ Rule, but how does the first equality in the last equation hold?

Comment: What is $A$, $B$, $\omega$, $\lambda$?

Comment: @kludg, I have updated the meaning of $A, B, \omega, \lambda$.

Comment: I guess mathematically the "objects" $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables and the author proves that PMF of their joint distribution is product of marginal PMF's. I think this is how independence of random variables is defined, and not clear why some proof is needed to the author.

Comment: @kludg, you are right, 1.12 is usually the definition of independence of random variables. However, I think the intention of author is to give the definition of independence of random variables intuitively from the first sentence of my quote, which leads to 1.10 and 1.11. Then 1.12 is something needed a proof, although it is equivalent to 1.10 and 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

My question is to derive
$$
p_{B \mid A}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{d_A-1} p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}{\sum_{j=0}^{d_A-1} p_A\left(\omega_j\right)},
$$
given A,B are independent variables and the definition of independence of random variables is
$$
p_{A \mid B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=p_{A \mid B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_n\right), \forall i, m, n.
$$
Starting from the definition of $P_{B|A}$,
$$
p_{B \mid A}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=\frac{p_{A B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)}{p_A\left(\omega_i\right)}. \quad (1)
$$
We multiply a unity to the (1), then,
$$
p_{B \mid A}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)=\frac{\sum_j p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}{\sum_j p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}\frac{p_{A B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)}{p_A\left(\omega_i\right)} = \frac{\sum_j p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}{\sum_j p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)/p_{A B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right) p_A\left(\omega_i\right)}. \quad (2)
$$
By the defintion of independence of random variables and Eq (1),
$$
\frac{p_{A B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)}{p_A\left(\omega_i\right)} = \frac{p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}{p_A\left(\omega_j\right)},
$$
then
$$
\frac{p_A\left(\omega_j\right)}{p_A\left(\omega_i\right)} = \frac{p_{A B}\left(\omega_j, \lambda_m\right)}{p_{A B}\left(\omega_i, \lambda_m\right)} \quad (3).
$$
Insert Eq (3) into Eq (2), we finish the derivation.